# cs50 program to increase and decrease volume of file

Tags: c, cs50

I have written this program for my Harvard cs50 project. It is increasing and decreasing volume of file input and then output result. I have cross-checked my code with other people solutions, and it is almost same. but yet am finding an error while checking it. below is my code.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
// Number of bytes in .wav header

const int HEADER_SIZE = 44;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Check command-line arguments
    if (argc != 4)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./volume input.wav output.wav factor\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Open files and determine scaling factor
    FILE *input = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (input == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open file.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *output = fopen(argv[2], "w");
    if (output == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open file.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    float factor = atof(argv[3]);
    uint16_t old_buffer[HEADER_SIZE];
    fread(old_buffer, HEADER_SIZE,1, input);
    fwrite(old_buffer,HEADER_SIZE,1, output);

    int16_t sample;
    while( fread(&sample, sizeof(int16_t), 1, input) != EOF)
    {
        sample= sample * factor;
        fwrite(&sample, sizeof(int16_t), 1, output);
    }

    fclose(input);
    fclose(output);
}
```

and the error I am getting is,

```
Results for cs50/labs/2023/x/volume generated by check50 v3.3.7
:) volume.c exists
:) volume.c compiles
:( reduces audio volume, factor of 0.5 correctly
    timed out while waiting for program to exit
:( reduces audio volume, factor of 0.1 correctly
    timed out while waiting for program to exit
:( increases audio volume, factor of 2 correctly
    timed out while waiting for program to exit
```

and if you guys been through the same thing or know how to fix this, please help

I thought the code is correct, but I don't what is the problem.

Comment: WAV files are *binary* files. Don't open them in text-mode.

Comment: Also note that `sample * factor` might overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`fread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread) returns a value *less* than the count if there's an error of end-of-file. That includes returning `0`.

You need to use `fread(...) == 1` as loop condition.

Comment: It works, appreciate it men.